# Hold a File operations untill a particular File operation is complete

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io

Hello I am working on WPF platform. I want to perform file operations like Unzip and move files at a button press. I want the program at button press to run `UnzipAndCreateUpdatePackage` method then wait for the operation to finish and then run the `Move Method` and then provide me with a confirmation.

---

**What I want to perform:**
Making the program wait until the Unzip is complete and then move the data from the unzipped folders. the current program gives me a file not found exception as the Unzipping process didn't finish.

---

How can I achieve this

Currently my code looks like this: **Button Tap event code**:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> FileNames = new List<string>();
        FileNames.Add("ApplicationData.zip");
        FileNames.Add("MapData.zip");
        FileNames.Add("LicenseData.zip");


        WithoutExtentionNameList = new List<string>();
        WithoutExtentionNameList.AddRange(FileNames);

        for (int item = 0; item < WithoutExtentionNameList.Count; item++)
        {
            WithoutExtentionNameList[item] = WithoutExtentionNameList[item].Replace(".zip", " ").TrimEnd();
        }

        UnZipAndCreateUpdatePackage(FileNames);

        moveData("LicenseTest 7.txt");
    }
```

**UnZipAndCreateUpdatePackage method code:**

```
private void UnZipAndCreateUpdatePackage(List<string> FileNameList)
    {
        string CheckPreviousData = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0]);
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(CheckPreviousData))
        {
            DeleteDirectory(CheckPreviousData);
        }

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(CheckPreviousData))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(CheckPreviousData);
        }

        foreach (var FileName in FileNameList)
        {

            if (FileName.Contains("Map"))
            {
                fileDestination = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0]);
            }

            //create a source file path
            sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileLocation, FileName);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceFile, fileDestination);
        }
        fileDestination = @"C:\Users\adity\Desktop\MapUpdaterTemp";

    }
```

**Movedata method:**

```
private void moveData(string LicenseFileName)
    {
        //Now Map the file data as per Update Package
        string MoveFrom = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0], WithoutExtentionNameList[2], LicenseFileName);
        string MoveTo = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0], WithoutExtentionNameList[1], LicenseFileName);

        System.IO.File.Move(MoveFrom, MoveTo);
    }
```

Comment: what sort of confirmation do you want? what is wrong with the code you are currently using? you can just call `MessageBox.Show()` after `moveData()` can't you?

Comment: @gilmishal the confirmation is not the issue. Making the program wait until the Unzip is complete and then move the data from the unzipped folders. the current program gives me a file not found exception as the Unzipping process didn't finish.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global boolean called something like bool extractNow = fase;

Then just add a while() statement to the code between the 2 keys that looks like this.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();   
sw.Start();

UnZipAndCreateUpdatePackage(FileNames);

while(!extractNow) //or extractNow == false
{

} 

sw.Stop();

TimeSpan milSecs = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
string timePassed = string.Format("{0:D2}d {1:D2}h:{2:D2}m:{3:D2}s",
            milSecs.Days, milSecs.Hours, milSecs.Minutes, milSecs.Seconds);

moveData("LicenseTest 7.txt");

MessageBox.Show("Extraction Completed in :" + timePassed.ToString());
```

Then add the bool as true at the end of the extract.

```
private void UnZipAndCreateUpdatePackage(List<string> FileNameList)
{
    string CheckPreviousData = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0]);
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(CheckPreviousData))
    {
        DeleteDirectory(CheckPreviousData);
    }

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(CheckPreviousData))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(CheckPreviousData);
    }

    foreach (var FileName in FileNameList)
    {

        if (FileName.Contains("Map"))
        {
            fileDestination = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileDestination, WithoutExtentionNameList[0]);
        }

        //create a source file path
        sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileLocation, FileName);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceFile, fileDestination);
    }
    fileDestination = @"C:\Users\adity\Desktop\MapUpdaterTemp";
    extractNow =false;
}
```

Its not pretty but it should work.